# How to check if a user has been refunded from the iOS paid app?

Tags: ios

My app is having a refund problem, you can see the following picture to better understand.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/content/attachment/7a0c3996-a3a3-4766-b989-09caad397be3

I suspect that users are taking advantage of Apple's refund policy to use my app for free. I am looking for a way to check if the user has had a refund to prevent them from accessing the app.

Currently, my guess is that when a user refunds their receipt their receipt will be revoked, so I plan to check "AppStoreReceiptUrl", if this field is null or empty then I will prevent them from using the app.

Is this correct way?
I hope to get your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to an actual paid app, that is, an app that you must pay to download, Apple already do this for you. If a user refunds their app, the app will not launch on any device with the corresponding receipt/s thereafter.

If you are experiencing refunds en-masse, you might want to look into why people are refunding the app and/or collecting feedback from users. It's likely a case of users feeling as though they aren't getting value for money if you're seeing large numbers of refunds.

Comment: Actually, I don't wonder if the number of downloads is more or less, or if there is a lot of variation, but any day there are many downloads, 1-2 days later almost all of those downloads will be refunded, you can look back in my picture, I'm not talking about ups and downs, it's going negative.
My App mainly serves a small community so few people know about it and I have not run any marketing campaigns yet. The app currently only has 1 rating of 5 stars and doesn't have any reviews yet.

Comment: I don't know what more to tell you unfortunately. We're getting into subjective territory here, so I will simply reiterate that, once an app is refunded, no installation that contains a receipt pertaining to a refunded transaction will be launchable.